# Too long section title in table of contents by using hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Some of titles are too long, and when I make the table of contents by adding the `\usepackage{hyperref}`, one line is not enough for them. When I add the `\usepackage{hyperref}`, the titles are out of the margin for page.
If I remove this package, the title is ok for me (because it can automatically divide into two lines).

How can this problem be solved?

I prefer to have the *full title in several lines* in the table of contents under the `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

The following is my code about this question.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=cyan,
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter 1}

\section{section 1 section 1 section 1 section 1 section 1 section 1}

\section{section 2 section 2 section 2 section 2 section 2 section 2 section     2 section 2 section 2 section 2 section 2 section 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I want the section 2 to divide into several lines with `hyperref` (that is the link can break into several lines) how can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: i think that something like `breaklinks` is called for here.  should be in the documentation for `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1):

Some drivers do not support links, which are broken across lines. Option `breaklinks` helps for a print version. The disadvantage is that it cannot enable broken link support magically. Therefore the link areas are quite wrong. For the table of contents the problem can be easily solved by using option `linktocpage`, which makes the page numbers instead of the section titles to links.